# Copy and move constructors of an input iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, c++-concepts

By the requeriments specified by the `std::input_iterator` concept, (and supperior iterators seems to be the same), they have to provide copy and move constructors:

```
input_iter<T>(const input_iter<T>& other) = default;
input_iter<T>(input_iter<T>&& other) noexcept = default;
```

Can they be defaulted? The typical implementation contains a private member pointing to some data:

```
private:
T* data;
```

Is in iterators a shallow copy/move the desired behaviour? I mean, copy/move the pointer itself, or must implement an explicit deep copy?

Comment: Where does the idea that iterators need to provide a move constructor come from? Iirc the only requirement is that iterators are copyable. A quick search on cppreference.com didn't yield this kind of requirement...

Comment: @fabian what kind of commentary is that one? Is completly irrelevant where does the idea come from. Also, a quick look in `cppreference` shows that `input iterator` concept must satisfiy `input_or_output_iterator`, that also must satisfy `weakly_incrementable`, that in the end, this last one must satisfy `movable`.

Comment: It's the type of comment that informs you that your assumption about `std::movable` is wrong: Even if there's only a copy constructor, the concept is satisfied, see the notes section to the closely related type trait [`std::is_move_constructible`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_move_constructible) and the [compiler output of gcc/clang/msvc on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/W6rYbc8bf)

Comment: @fabian now at least, your comment is a helpful one. The concept still has to satisfy `std::movable`, and that means that must be `trivially_move_constructible`. So, if you don't provide one, isn't the same as explictly mark it as `default`? I could write a better question avoiding the part about the move ctr, when I was only worried about the ownership of the data (ie, I didn't have idea is the `default` impl was correct, or I was needed to perform a deep (copy/move))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterators don't own the pointed object, they just point to it. So copying whatever member pointers suffices.